# storybook should not compile when there are typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, babel-loader, fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin

I am using storybook with typescript and babel-loader to compile both ts and js files in storybook webpack and project webpack.
Babel-loader is not throwing errors when I run storybook, when my files have typescript errors.
One approach is to add a tsc command in my package.json, but thi isn't what I want to do.
I therefore added fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin in my webpack config to check for typescript errors.
Project is now throwing errors on running storybook but it is still running despite having ts errors.
The behaviour I want is that storybook should not run when there are ts errors.

Please help with the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have 2 webpack configs?
> I am using storybook with typescript and babel-loader to compile both ts and js files in storybook webpack and project webpack.

What version of storybook are you using?

Comment: storybook v5.3.21 and yes I have 2 configs, one for storybook, inside storybook folder and one for the project build which is in parallel to src folder

Comment: Are you able to upgrade it to Storybook v6? It adds sane defaults for typescript. You won't have to configure it at all.

Comment: Storybook supoorts a version of react which I am not using. Hence cannot update